# How to generate username of specific pattern in drupal during registration

Tags: module, drupal-7, registration

I want to generate a `usernames` st + **first two** initials of their `first name` + their `last name`.

There are few modules to create `username` of specific pattern but none of them can accomplish my requirement. I am not `Drupal` module expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to install the [automatic username](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_username) module:

Navigate to the configuration page of this module: admin/config/people/accounts/patterns

Then, in the "Other settings" section you can check the option "Evaluate PHP in pattern."

This allows you to execute PHP in the "Pattern for username" field. Two things to consider:

1. PHP is executed after the token replacement, this allows you to actually manipulate the strings.
2. You need to `echo` the final result.

Make sure that the php is wrapped with `<?php ?>` tags. Also, if you make a syntax error, it will only be seen upon registration (Or whenever the script is executed.)

Now let's say you configured your users to have a `first_name` field and a `last_name` field (with those specific field names)

Your PHP could look something like this:

```
<?php 
  $initials = substr("[user:field-first-name]", 0, 2);
  echo 'str' . $initials . "[user:field-last-name]";
?>
```

First, Note that the token are between double quotes to make sure that what is outputted by the token is considered a string by PHP

Second, the php function [substr](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.substr.php) is used to get the 2 first letters of the first name.

Now, things I don't know

- I have no idea what happens if two users happen to have the same resulting username
- I don't know what happen if a user enters a double quote in his name, might be dangerous, you might want to escape it with a `str_replace` or something like that

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. I ended up making custom module. But your solution is perfect! Thanks again for your time.

Comment: No problem! I actually did not know anything about this module and your question made me look into it! Thanks to you!